# Select One Menu renderizado

Tags: jsf, aplicação-web, maven

Boa tarde, eu tenho dois selects one menu, um carrega os estados e outro eu quero carregar as cidades daquele estado em tempo de execução, só que não consigo, ele não carrega nem a página quando tento usar `<p:ajax>` ou `<f:ajax>`, alguém pode me dar uma mão:

Bean

```
 private EstadoDAO edao = new EstadoDAO();
private List<Estado> estados;
private int estadoSelecionado;

private CidadeDAO cdao = new CidadeDAO();
private List<Cidade> cidades;
private int cidadeSelecionada;


public pessoaMB() {
    estados = edao.MostrarEstados();

}

public void atualizarCidadesporEstado() {
    cidades = cdao.MostrarCidadesporEstado(estadoSelecionado);
}
```

Minha tela:

```
                    <div class="ui-g-12">
                        <h:selectOneMenu id="estado" value="#{pessoaMB.estadoSelecionado}"  >
                            <f:selectItems value="#{pessoaMB.estados}" var="estado" itemValue="#{estado.idEstado}" itemLabel="#{estado.nomeEstado}"/>
                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                        <p:ajax update="cidade" listener="#{pessoaMB.atualizarCidadesporEstado()}"/>  
                    </div>

                    <div class="ui-g-12">
                        <p:outputLabel  value="Selecione sua cidade:*"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-g-12">
                        <h:selectOneMenu id="cidade" value="#{pessoaMB.cidadeSelecionada}" >
                            <f:selectItems value="#{pessoaMB.cidades}" var="cidade" itemValue="#{cidade.idCidade}" itemLabel="#{cidade.nomeCidade}"/>
                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                    </div>
```

Os métodos DAO funcionam perfeitamente, meu problema é quando tento aplicar um ajax, ele fica com a página assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Muito provavelmente minha lógica está errada, já usei ajax com radio button em outros formulários e funcionou perfeitamente, se alguém puder dar um norte eu agradeço.

*Já vi os exemplos de select com rendered, nenhum funcionou até o momento comigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está usando primefaces certo?

Tente colocar fazer o ajax no evento de onblur

Assim

```
<p:ajax update="cidade" event="blur" listener="#{pessoaMB.atualizarCidadesporEstado()}"/>
```

Comment: Deu o mesmo erro de redirecionamento incorreto, só me diga, essa lógica que eu apliquei deveria funcionar ? E o meu método não é um evento, não sei como ele deveria ser pra funcionar

Comment: Sim é assim mesmo, estava vendo aqui uma coisa, coloque o p:ajax "dentro" do selectOneMenu

Comment: Abaixo o exemplo no primefaces showcase https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/dropdown.xhtml

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado, a única é que ele precisa clicar em alguma outra parte da tela pra renderizar, mas isso eu me viro, valeu mesmo!